# Need to close the scheduler after the job is scheduled?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Situation:
I'm running Strut web application in which we have used QuartzSchduler. The apllication is running fine but sometimes it shutsdown automaically.
I have analyzed the logs and found the pattern, the last process invokde is QuartzScheduler before the app is going to die.

MyQuestion:
There was start method for scheduler in my code, it's need to be closed after schduling the jobs?

```
Trigger ContentDataTrigger =
        TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("anyTriggerName", "group1")
                .withSchedule(
                        CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/15 * * * ?"))
                .build();
Trigger ImageDataTrigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("anyTriggerName", "group2")
        .withSchedule(
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *"))
        .build();
Trigger VideoDataTrigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("anyTriggerName", "group3")
        .withSchedule(
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 25 0/1 1/1 * ? *"))
        .build();

Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(contentJob,ContentDataTrigger);
scheduler.scheduleJob(imageJob,ImageDataTrigger);
scheduler.scheduleJob(videoJob,VideoDataTrigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scheduler.start()` starts the threads that fire the triggers.

If you call `scheduler.shtudown()` it stops executing the jobs. I don't think it's the behaviour you want.